# How to render an animation in EEVEE with Anti Aliasing off?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, antialiasing

Yo, I'm somewhat new to blender, but i've been practicing with the EEVEE engine and  making low poly models, but I'd like to render model turntables without anti-aliasing if that makes any sense, here's an example of what i'd like to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqB8I.jpg 
I've looked at some tutorials but I couldn't find anything as specific as what I want to achieve, and since im new to this I just assume that type of render has to do with anti-aliasing

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable sample from nearby pixel to turn off anti-aliasing effect in EEVEE. The detail can be found in [here](/questions/129636/how-does-anti-aliasing-work-in-cycles).

**Properties Panel**: *Scene → Film →* `Filter Size: 0.00 px`

[image]

Once you disable the anti-aliasing, you can now scale up the final render to emphasis on that jagged part.

### Compositing method:

[image]

Or using a value to change it for ease:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful, its helping me getting close to what I want to achieve, granted I think I'm doing something wrong, here are some test results https://imgur.com/a/BHcie50 basically if use 0.050 and 20.000, it comes out in the size I want but way too pixelated, and if I mess up with those settings I get results where the character is way too small or super close to the camera

Comment: @2Fleur2 You can use a math node to do with that value, see the update answer